# When put in a function calculation stops working in r

Tags: r

Here is how the data looks:

```
         V1       V2   V3      V4           V5 V6   V7
1 1002000000 20180317 1PAC 000000000011000+ 33 33 6171985
2 1002000001 20050202 1PRM 000000000017376+ 20 20 7011985
3 1002000001 20050503 1PRM 000000000017376+ 20 20 7011985
4 1002000001 20050803 1PRM 000000000017376+ 21 21 7011985
5 1002000001 20051031 1PRM 000000000017376+ 21 21 7011985
6 1002000001 20060130 1PRM 000000000017376+ 21 21 7011985
```

Here is my code:

```
ULtrans <- read.table("ULTRANS.txt", sep = "", header = F)
ULtrans <- ULtrans[,-c(5,6)] #remove unused columns
names(ULtrans) <- c("pol_num", "trans_date", "type", "amt", "iss_date")
convert_amt <- function(x){
  as.integer(substr(x,1,nchar(x)-1))*ifelse(substr(x,nchar(x),nchar(x))=="-",-1,1)
}
ULtrans$amt <- convert_amt(as.character(ULtrans$amt))
ULtrans$trans_date <- ymd(ULtrans$trans_date) 
ULtrans$iss_date <- mdy(ULtrans$iss_date)
```

I tried to put this in a method because I have to clean up several files in the same manner. I put it in a method that looks like this:

```
format_trans <- function(x){
x[,-c(5,6)]
names(x) <- c("pol_num", "trans_date", "type", "amt", "iss_date")

convert_amt <- function(x){
as.integer(substr(x,1,nchar(x)-1))*ifelse(substr(x,nchar(x),nchar(x))=="-",-1,1)
}
x$amt <- convert_amt(as.character(x$amt))

x$trans_date <- ymd(x$trans_date) 
x$iss_date <- mdy(x$iss_date)
}
```

When I try to use the method I made it gives me a warning message. "All formats failed to parse. No formats found." When I don't use the method I get the cleaned dates and transaction amounts.

Comment: `x[,-c(5, 6)]` is not doing anything.

Comment: It should be `x <- x[, -c(5, 6)]` if I check the other code

Comment: agreed. I called format_trans(ULtrans) and this did nothing to ULtrans. Why is this the case? 
I was able to fix the error by adding return(x) and instead of just calling ULtrans:
ULtrans <- format_trans(ULtrans)
but I am still confused why this is necessary

Comment: It is because you are returning the value of the last assignment instead of the actual x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two problems in your code. First, you're using the wrong syntax to remove the unnecessary columns. Second, you're not returning the cleaned data.frame at the end, so it only exist inside the function environment.

I've pasted your example data in a file. Here's a suggestion: since you're going to clean many files with the same format, you can put `read.table` inside the function. You can also select the columns you want in the same line.

```
read.and.clean <- function(file) {

  require('lubridate')

  ULtrans <- read.table(file)[c(1:4,7)]
  names(ULtrans) <- c("pol_num", "trans_date", "type", "amt", "iss_date")

  convert_amt <- function(x){
    as.integer(substr(x,1,nchar(x)-1))*ifelse(substr(x,nchar(x),nchar(x))=="-",-1,1)
  }

  ULtrans$amt <- convert_amt(as.character(ULtrans$amt))
  ULtrans$trans_date <- ymd(ULtrans$trans_date) 
  ULtrans$iss_date <- mdy(ULtrans$iss_date)

  return(ULtrans)
}

df <- read.and.clean("example.txt")

> df
     pol_num trans_date type   amt   iss_date
1 1002000000 2018-03-17 1PAC 11000 1985-06-17
2 1002000001 2005-02-02 1PRM 17376 1985-07-01
3 1002000001 2005-05-03 1PRM 17376 1985-07-01
4 1002000001 2005-08-03 1PRM 17376 1985-07-01
5 1002000001 2005-10-31 1PRM 17376 1985-07-01
6 1002000001 2006-01-30 1PRM 17376 1985-07-01
```

OBS: It's always nice to inform any additional package required for your example to work.